# profanities in written cantonese blurred out

Tags: usage, cantonese, colloquialisms

I was watching a youtube video published by a famous populist news channel from Hong Kong. The topic was about food and featured comments from viewers saying that it "was F***ing delicious". There were likewise Cantonese comments with these profanities used to express this 'superlativeness' in taste.

One such cantonese comment was 好X食, where the "X" is blurred out since this was shown in Youtube.

My question is, what could be these possible colloquial/profanities being blurred out to express extremely tastefulness of the dish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four of the five  "Big Five Profanity Words of Guangdong ([廣東粗口五大字](https://evchk.wikia.org/zh/wiki/%E5%BB%A3%E6%9D%B1%E7%B2%97%E5%8F%A3%E4%BA%94%E5%A4%A7%E5%AD%97))" can be used as a superlative before an adjective. The one that couldn't is '屌', which is strictly a verb for 'f..k'

To use a swearing word as a superlative, it must be placed after the superlative adverb and before the adjective, not inserted between the two characters of the adjective, e.g. 好**X**食 roughly means 'tasty **my ass**'= not tasty at all

The correct form:

好食 = delicious

好好食 = very delicious

好X好食 = very damn delicious (better than very delicious)

> "撚" is the most common one in this kind of phrase